# A script to start backend and frontend at the same time

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am python developer mostly. During development, I used to create a one liner shell script to run my python projects such as:

run.bat

```
@ECHO ON  
cmd.exe /C "cd backend && pipenv run python manage.py runserver"
```

OR

run.sh

```
pipenv run python backend/manage.py runserver
```

Recently started with react projects, thus wanted to modify above code to start the react project at the same time. I tried adding below code in my `run.bat` file from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678482/running-react-and-flask-using-a-single-shell-script), but no luck.

```
    cmd.exe /C "cd frontend && npm start" &
    cmd.exe /C "cd backend && pipenv run python manage.py runserver"
```

It starts the first command and nothing happens unless I quit react project.

Answer (score 1):

Update your script as follow:

```sh
start cmd.exe /C "cd frontend && npm start"
start cmd.exe /C "cd backend && pipenv run python manage.py runserver"
```

Tell me if it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you. it's kind of working but its starting totally 2 separate shells from the original command. Can we run at least 1 command in same shell and let the other open the separate tab/window